# Stop user from inputting letters into html input tag based on variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a word game where the user gets a string of 8 letters and they must make as many words as they can out of them. I am trying to make it so that they can only type the letters from the 8 letter string. I am having trouble making it so that it blocks the letters based on the variable which is the 8 letter string.

Here is my code:

```js
// Choosing random letters for game (3 vowels, 5 consonants)
function getRandomCharsFromString(str, length) {
  return Array.from({
    length
  }, () => {
    return str[Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)]
  });
}

function shuffle(str) {
  var a = str.split(""),
    n = a.length;

  for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a.join("");
}

function getRandomString() {
  var vowels = 'aeiou';
  var consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz';

  var randomVowels = getRandomCharsFromString(vowels, 3);
  var randomConsonants = getRandomCharsFromString(consonants, 5);

  var randomWord = [...randomVowels, ...randomConsonants].join('')
  return shuffle(randomWord)
}

//Setting the letter variable to nothing
var letters = "";

//Showing letters generated in the gameplay interface
function newGame() {
  words = 0;
  document.querySelector('.gameplay').style.display = 'flex';
  letters = getRandomString();
  document.querySelector('#wordcount').innerHTML = `${words}&nbsp;`;
  document.querySelector('#gameletters').innerHTML = `${letters}`;
  console.log(letters);
}

//Preventing player from using letters that aren't in the word
function keyPressed(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
  if (e.key == `${letters}`) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the necessary html to your question's snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here

```
if (e.key == `${letters}`) {
```

This tests if the key pressed, in `e.key` is *equal to* the string `letters`, which it will never be.

There are a couple of other ways you could test.

```js
if (letters.indexOf(e.key) > -1) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
// or
if (letters.includes(e.key)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Anything that returns true else returns false can be shortened to just return the results of the test:

```js
return (letters.includes(e.key));
```

Another way would be to turn the *letters* string into an array and use `.includes()` — but really only if you have some *other* reason to want an array.

```js
return letters.split('').includes(e.key);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `key` event property is going to be a single character/letter. Your 8-character string is not going to equate to just one. You have a number of quick-to-implement options. Here's my suggested update, assuming you are attaching `keyPressed` to the `keypress` event handler:

```
function keyPressed(e) {
    console.log(e.key);
    if (letters.includes(e.key)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or, a slightly more compressed version:

```
function keyPressed(e) {
    return letters.includes(e.key);
}
```